# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \max (x, 1-x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a question related to definite integrals and series from this site [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Maximum.html).

It is written that the definite integral of $\max(x,1-x)dx$ from $0$ to $1$ is equal to $\frac34$:

$$ \int_0^1 \max (x, 1-x) dx = \frac34$$

but I have question, there are two different cases (I don't consider when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, because in this case it is undefined which one is maximum), but in the second case, if $x<0$, then it is clear that $1-x$ is  greater than $x$, so its integral is $x-x^2/2$, and after plugging values,we get $1/2$, and on the other hand, if $x>1$, then $x$ is maximum, its antiderivative is $x^2$ so we get $1/2$, so when is it equal to $3/4$? Please help me to understand this problem.

Comment: >>*i don't consider when x is between 0 and 1,because in this case it is undefined which one is maximum*-No, it is surely defined. $\max\{x,1-x\}=x\forall x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$, else otherwise. So you have to split the range of integration into two halves $\int_0^\frac{1}{2}(1-x)dx+\int_\frac{1}{2}^1xdx=...$

Comment: @dato Look here is what it looks like: [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+1-x+++%2C+y+%3D+x).

Comment: When you have "∫" with a number below and above it, you can say that you integrate from the lower number to the upper number with respect to the variable after the "d".  So, you can read this as saying "the integral from 0 to 1 of the maximum of x and 1-x with respect to x."  Thus, you x cannot equal anything less than 0 for this problem nor anything greater than 1, x can only take on values between, and including, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $1-x\geq x$ when $x\leq1/2$ and $x\geq 1-x$ when $x>1/2$, we have
$$\max (x, 1-x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    1-x, & \hbox{if }x\leq1/2; \\
    x, & \hbox{if }x>1/2.
  \end{array}
\right.$$
Hence, 
$$\int_0^1 \max (x, 1-x) dx =\int_0^{1/2} \max (x, 1-x) dx +\int_{1/2}^1 \max (x, 1-x) dx$$
$$=\int_0^{1/2} (1-x)dx +\int_{1/2}^1 x dx=(x-\frac{x^2}{2})\Big|_0^{1/2}+\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_{1/2}^1=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: i see @Paul thanks a lot of,my  problem  was that,i didn't   take care  about range of  x  and  did not consider   what happens at two different case,just only took one case   and  even more then range,so thanks a lot,i understood everything

Comment: @dato: You are welcome. It's good that it helps. Merry Christmas!

Comment: you too  @Paul  Merry  Christmas

Comment: Good analysis!!

Comment: In a sense, this is the hard way.  The integral is just the area of a square minus the area of a triangle.  You don't need antiderivatives.

Answer (score 4):

This integral, viewed as the area under the graph of a function, is just the area of a square minus the area of a triangle---that's what the graph of the function looks like.  So
$$
(\text{base}\times\text{height}) - \left(\frac12\times\text{base}\times\text{height}\right) = (1\times1)-\left(\frac12\times 1\times\frac12\right)=1-\frac14=\frac34.
$$

Answer (score 3):

This isn't that different from Paul's answer, but I wanted an excuse to use Iverson brackets. Recall that the Iverson bracket $[p]$ is equal to $1$ if condition $p$ is true, and $0$ if $p$ is false. We also have the relation $[\lnot p]=1-[p]$.

We then have

$$\begin{align*}
\max(x,1-x)&=x[x\geq 1-x]+(1-x)(1-[x\geq1-x])\\
&=1-x+(2x-1)\left[x\geq\frac12\right]
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \max(x, 1-x)\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1 \left(1-x+(2x-1)\left[x\geq\frac12\right]\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1 (1-x) \mathrm dx+\int_0^1 (2x-1)\left[x\geq\frac12\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1 (1-x) \mathrm dx+\int_{\frac12}^1 (2x-1)\mathrm dx\\
&=\left.\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right|_0^1+\left.\left(x^2-x\right)\right|_{\frac12}^1=\frac12+\frac14=\frac34
\end{align*}$$